# Uncaught SyntaxError: Кавычки ломают title с БД

Tags: javascript

У меня с БД приходят значение айтемов для таблицы.
В 'title' могут приходить названия внутри которых могут быть разные кавычки: ' " `

[image: Пример ошибки]
[image: Пример ошибки 2]

Использовать ' - невозможно по причине несовместимости с IE11.
' и " - все равно ломают несколько важных документов.

Как лучше добавить title в объект, что бы не было :" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier " и все тайтлы были валидными?

replace не очень помог, так как он воспринимает как строку только первую часть текста до кавычки...

Comment: "с БД приходят значение" - ??

Comment: @Igor имел в виду, что я не могу менять title вручную, что очень упростило бы задачу.

Comment: Что значит "с БД приходят значения", знаете только Вы. Компоновка данных в JS на сервере должна производиться с использованием соответствующих серверных инструментов для "енкодирования" этих данных. Что на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте конкатенацию строк, сейчас у вас просто прерывается строка и вылетает эксепшн:

```js
title: 'строка' + "с" + 'конкатенацией'
```

Либо надо делать [экранирование символов](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-escaping), то есть если у вас встречается символ `'` или `"` до последнего закрывающего символа, то экранируйте его:

```js
title: 'строка\' \"с \" \"экранированием\'\"'
```

Ещё вы можете написать свой парсер для [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), читайте про `reviver`, там вы можете например задать обработчик (который принимает `key, value`), проверять ключ, если `title`, то делать кастомную обработку, иначе просто верните `value`.

Comment: Не могу менять тайтлы вручную. 
Но идея хорошая с конкатенацией хорошая, можно написать функцию которая будет проверять есть ли "кавычки" в тайтле, если есть то нужно их экранировать. Но все же, надеялся что есть попроще способ

Comment: @Andrew, обновил ответ, возможно третий вариант вам подойдет. Я просто думал, что у вас проблема с упаковкой, а не с распаковкой данных. Для большей информации не могли вы описать, что у вас на сервере, потому в JSON в любом случае строка должна быть javascript-валидной. Было бы неплохо приложить пример одного такого айтема из не распакованного json'а.